# Weird location header in HTTPS request to Facebook using .Net's SslStream

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl

I'm writing my own HTTP client implementation using over TCP socket.

**The problem is that it works on everywhere I've tested except HTTPS to "facebook.com".** My code would return the HTTP header in the response:

```
Location: https://www.facebook.comhttps://facebook.com/
```

Which obviously prevents my code from following the 301 response. I compared my results with Fiddler; in Fiddler it shows this header correctly:

```
Location: https://www.facebook.com/
```

I've tested on a few large sites including Bing, Amazon, Google and Yahoo, and the headers obtained in my code are identical to those in Fiddler. Even in the Facebook response, every header I get is identical to Fiddler except that one Location header.

**Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is it a bug of .NET's SslStream, or a bug of Facebook?**

---

I have the following code:

```
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(_uri.Host, _uri.Port);

Stream stream;
if (_uri.Scheme == "https") {
    var secureStream = new System.Net.Security.SslStream(tcp.GetStream());
    try {
        secureStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_uri.Host);
        stream = secureStream;
    }
    catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException e) {
        secureStream.Close();
        throw e;
    }
} else stream = tcp.GetStream();
```

I write to the stream using:

```
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII);
```

Later, I have my own reader which processes the stream at byte level. Here's is the snippet for reading HTTP headers:

```
public string ReadLine() {
    var s = ReadUntil(0x0D);
    if (_stream.Read(_buffer, 0, 1) != 1) throw new EndOfStreamException();
    if (_buffer[0] != 0x0A) throw new FormatException("Expecting '\\n' after '\\r'");

    return s;
}

public static string ExtractAsciiString(byte[] array, int length) {
    if (length == 0) return string.Empty;

    string s;
    unsafe {
        fixed (byte* p = &array[0]) {
            s = new String((sbyte*)p, 0, length);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: A simple test with sending a HTTP request with some SSL client does not show this behavior. This means it is probably a problem of your code, maybe caused by some malformed request. But what you currently show from the code is insufficient to debug the problem or even reproduce it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I only get this in my own code as well. However, *no body* uses .NET's SslStream to send requests, so I'm not sure whether it is .NET's bug, or my problem. A malformed request should not lead to a malformed response, and like I said, it works everywhere else.

Comment: A malformed request can lead to anything because it is not expected. And especially for malformed requests it is not uncommon that different servers show different behavior. Code receiving malformed data often just treats it as valid which will result in strange behavior. And I'm very much doubt that this is a problem of SSLStream since this should be agnostic to the actual payloads, i.e. just cares about bytes.